# Retrieving data from database and passing it as instance of entity

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony4

I'm trying to pass id from query from one database table to another table to which is related.
But, since they are related I have to pass it as instance of the entity(class) to which is related.
This is error I got:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\KeywordRating::setKeywordId() must be an instance of App\Entity\Keywords, integer given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\ratingAPI\src\Service\KeywordRatingService.php on line 26

This is my code:

```
public function insertRating($params, ObjectManager $manager, KeywordsRepository $keyRep, ProvidersRepository $provRep)
{
    $keywordId = $keyRep->checkKeyword(strtolower($params['keyword']))->getId();
    $providerId = $provRep->checkProvider($params['provider'])->getId();

    $rating = new KeywordRating();
    $rating->setKeywordId(<Keywords instance> $keywordId);
    $rating->setProviderId(<Providers instance> $providerId);
    if($params['attr'] === 'rocks')
    {
        $rating->setRocksRating($params['rating']);
        $rating->setSucksRating(0);
    } else 
    {
        $rating->setRocksRating(0);
        $rating->setSucksRating($params['rating']);
    }
    $rating->setRocksVotes(10);
    $rating->setSucksVotes(8);
    $rating->setSumVotes(18);
    $rating->setScore(2.50);

    $manager->persist($rating);
    $manager->flush();
}
```

This is sql query:

```
public function checkKeyword($keyword)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('k')
        ->where('k.keyword_name = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $keyword)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

checkProvider() is the same, only different parameters.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a namespace called Entities where you have all your entities classes, you can try something like this:

```
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder->select('keyword')
                ->from('App\Entity\Keywords', 'keyword')
                ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('keyword.keyword_name', $queryBuilder->expr()->literal($keyword)));

    $result = $queryBuilder->getQuery()-> getOneOrNullResult();

    return $result;
```

Comment: Your issue is you are passing an Id but that method is expecting and entity, take a look to the line you are getting the $keywordId variable, you have a getId() method at the end, remove that one and everything should be fine.